# How to implement GLOBAL Modifier + Click or Force touch event (SwiftUI MacOS)

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Is there a way to globally listen for events that involve a mouse click or touchpad click? Like Command + Click or Force touch (MacOS).

Google didn't help.

I tried searching through Github, I only found libraries that set global hotkeys without mouse clicks.